# Abstract appoach to multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

(I have posted a similar question hours ago, but I deleted that and slightly modified the question and reposting it here.)

So far, I have studied all undergraduate courses only except Green's theorem and Stoke's theorem.

As far as I know, to prove the most general form of Stoke's theorem, one must know some sophisticated algebras. (Tensor algebra, Exterior algebra and etc) I like this approach but it seems like I have to learn so many things to achieve this. **Anyway, what are the rigorous texts introducing this general form of Stoke's theorem**?

Moreover, while the general form of Stoke's theorem requires lots of prerequisites, Green's theorem seems much easier to prove than Stoke's theorem in abstract context.

I'm not asking for a very top generalized setting of Green's theorem. Just like one learns Cauchy's Integral formula with relation of homotopy theory in graduate school while one learns it for a simple closed curve (without knowledge of homotopy theory), **I'm curious whether there is a text treating Green's theorem and related multivariable calculus in graduate-level abstract setting**.

Say $\alpha$ is a differentiable simple closed curve one is applying Green's theorem on. And consider a rectifiable simple closed curve $\beta$ which is homotopic to $\alpha$ rel $\{0,1\}$. Such $\beta$ can be chosen very close to $\alpha$ so I think the area difference of interiors of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be made arbitrarily small or zero. I think to make this assertion precise, one needs lebesgue measure to control areas.

Even though a text does not cover what I just described, what is an abstract text treating multivariable calculus that you know? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I learned about Stokes' Theorem from Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds."  This is probably my favorite text so I'll recommend it to you :)

Comment: Language does not matter if there is an outstanding text. I have a passion to use dictionaries and translators to read a text if there is the one I'm looking for..

Comment: @AlvinJin Thank you! I will check for it.